# Facebook Login GraphResponse Error Android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-login

I am following the Facebook documentation to implement facebook login to get only `AccessToken` (not other user information) into my android app. but every time I login it comes with a weird error..I was using api key supplied by client(in development mod) for my app but it had the same error then I created one facebook app with the same details and made it live as I ve seen some solutions suggesting that the app should be live so I have created a live app and checked facebook Id credentials at my end all are fine but still I get this error when trying to login .
i.e when i click on LoginButton progress shows up and it vanishes away and i get an error stating

**Error**

> com.mtlab.test E/GraphResponse: {HttpStatus: 404, errorCode: 803,
>   subErrorCode: -1, errorType: OAuthException, errorMessage: (#803) Some
>   of the aliases you requested do not exist: 21312289922111}

**Gradle:**

```
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:[4,5)'
```

**My code that I used to login is:**

```
callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
               AccessToken token = loginResult.getAccessToken();
               if(token!=null){
                   FacebookAuthToken = token.toString();
                   sendFacebookDataToServer();
               }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                // App code
                Log.d("Fb","canceled");
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                // App code
                Log.d("Fb","error");
            }
        });
```

**In Manifest:**

```
<meta-data
            tools:replace="android:value"
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />
  <activity
            android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data android:scheme="@string/fb_login_protocol_scheme" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

I have followed to same process mentioned in documentation but nothing happened.

Comment: What *fields* are you requesting at a time of *graph API call* ?

Comment: @JayRathodRJ I dont need any fields just acces token is required and it didnt mention anything about graph api call for facebook login

Answer (score 1):

Use this Code ..... i have also used it ..working fine in my application...

```
 CallbackManager callbackManager;
 LoginManager loginManager;
```

In onCreate

```
FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());            
FacebookSdk.addLoggingBehavior(LoggingBehavior.INCLUDE_ACCESS_TOKENS);
setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);

callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
loginManager = com.facebook.login.LoginManager.getInstance();
loginManager.registerCallback(callbackManager, this);
```

Onclick or where you want to open Facebook

```
 private void facebookLogin() {
        loginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(this, Arrays.asList("email", "public_profile"));
    }
```

After that

```
@Override
    public void onSuccess(final LoginResult loginResult) {

        if (loginResult != null) {

            Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();

            if (profile != null) {
                firstName = profile.getFirstName();
                lastName = profile.getLastName();
                social_id = profile.getId();
                profileURL = String.valueOf(profile.getProfilePictureUri(200, 200));
                Log.e(TAG, "social Id: " + profileURL);
            }



GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(loginResult.getAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {

      Log.e("","token"+loginResult.getAccessToken().getToken());    //here is your access token             

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });

            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
            parameters.putString("fields", "id,first_name,name,last_name,email,gender,birthday");
            request.setParameters(parameters);
            request.executeAsync();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancel() {
        Log.e("bug", "facebook sign in connection cancel");
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(FacebookException error) {
        UiHelper.showToast(this, "An error occur during Facebook Login");
        Log.e("bug", "facebook sign in error" + error.toString());
    }
```

In app build.gradle file

```
  compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+'
```

In manifest

```
 <meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />
```

And also add

```
class YourActivity implements FacebookCallback<LoginResult>
```

Comment: thanks I found the issue actually i degraded the library to 4.+ and it started working fine